# left outer join: get column values selectively

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables -

`users: id, email, phone_number, created_on`

`registered_users: id, user_id, email, registered_on, status`

`users` will always have a record, while a record will be inserted in `registered_users` only when the user is registered.

My requirement is to list all users, registered or not, and show their email addresses. For all the records in `users`, I need to display the email address from `registered_users` as long as there is a record in it; otherwise, I need to display the email address from the `users` table.

I need a left outer join. But how do I selectively extract values for the same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.email, u.email) AS email
FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN registered_users AS r USING (id)
```

I'm assuming a given value of `id` corresponds to the same user in both tables.

COALESCE() returns its first non-null argument.

If there is no matching row in registered_users, then the outer join returns NULL for all columns, and in that case, the select defaults to the users.email. If there is a matching row in registered_users, then its email will be returned first.